# Get frontmost subview

Tags: iphone, uiview, touches

I know UIView's `hitTest:withEvent:` method digs down to the far-most view that gets the touch event, but how would you get the opposite result? The first view to get an event at a certain `CGPoint`?

**EDIT**
As zem pointed out, that hitTest method returns the farthest descendent in the view hierarchy. In my case, I have a mapView with a bunch of pinViews on it and I wanna get the frontmost pin at a certain CGPoint. That hitTest method keeps returning `MKAnnotationContainerView`, which I assume is a UIView that contains all my pinViews. How do I make it return the pinView itself and not its furthest descendant?

Comment: To clarify something, `hitTest` doesn't return the "far-most view"; by "farthest descendent," they mean the deepest in the view hierarchy. In most cases this *will* be the view in the "front" of the screen where the user touched. The first view to get an event will likely be something uninformative like the `UIView` belonging to the current view controller that takes up the whole screen. Are you sure this is what you want, and that `hitTest` doesn't already do what you want?